# Кликнуть по ссылке в Webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Загруженная страница содержит ссылки вида:

`<a class="click" href="javascript:void(0)">Click here</a>`

при нажатии на которые должна появляться необходимая информация. Я пытаюсь сделать это программно следующим образом:

```
HtmlElementCollection a_tag = wb1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement he in a_tag)
{
    if (he.InnerHtml == "Click here")
        he.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

но получить необходимую "инфу" не получается. В чем проблема или как это можно сделать по-другому?